# avoid to cast element pointer type of a container

Tags: c++, casting, containers

I have a function where I need vector of pointers to `Base` and a `Derived` type. And I have a function which should be able to handle with both container types, because it simply call only virtual functions all defined in `Base`.

If given the element pointers direct is no problem like:

```
void Func(Base*);
Derived* d;
Func(d);  // works perfect
```

But having a container type, it becomes a ugly and dangerous. If and only if the container type is fully equivalent for both pointer types the cast will work. That is typically true because all known implementations of standard containers implement pointer types as derived from `void*` to minimize the footprint as I know.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base
{   
    public: virtual void Func() {std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }
};  

class Derived: public Base
{   
    public:
        void Func() override { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; }
        void MoreFunc(){ std::cout << "SomeMoreFunc" << std::endl; } 
};  

// This function should "eat" also vector<Derived*>
// this can be simply done by using templates, 
// but results in doubling the code in memory while
// two instances will be created with exact the same
// content and they will not be optimized away ( gcc ).
void DoSomething( std::vector<Base*>& vec )
{   
    for ( auto& el: vec ) { el->Func();}   
}   

int main()
{   
    std::vector< Base*> vecBase;
    vecBase.push_back( new Base );
    vecBase.push_back( new Base );

    std::vector< Derived*> vecDerived;
    vecDerived.push_back( new Derived );
    vecDerived.push_back( new Derived );

    DoSomething( vecBase );
    DoSomething( (std::vector<Base*>&)vecDerived ); // that cast I want to avoid!

    for ( auto& el: vecDerived ) { el->MoreFunc(); }   
}
```

How can I avoid the bad cast for the vector element type here?
Do a full copy of the container is a alternative but waste also code and run time.

Is there a "typical" solution for such problems?

And yes, DoSomething inside is more complex as given in that minimal example. So simply removing for() to foreach/lambda has no chance and also calling the function inside DoSomething from the outside did not fit my real world problem here. And also it must be kept in mind, that for_each itself will generate more template instances here which is exactly the opposite of what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::for_each` from `<algorithm>` and a lambda to do that:

```
auto func = [](Base *ptr) { ptr->Func(); };
std::for_each(vecBase.begin(), vecBase.end(), func);
std::for_each(vecDerived.begin(), vecDerived.end(), func);
```

Or define your function as it follows:

```
void DoSomething(Base* ptr) {   
    ptr->Func();
}
```

And use it with `std::for_each`:

```
std::for_each(vecBase.begin(), vecBase.end(), DoSomething);
std::for_each(vecDerived.begin(), vecDerived.end(), DoSomething);
```

No templates at all in both cases.
Well, to be honest, no templates in your code. `std::for_each` is a function template, but `DoSomething` won't. Not sure it's what you were looking for.

---

**Edit after comments**

The best way to avoid templates at all is to get the loop out of `DoSomething`.
Any function that accepts a `Base *` will be fine in this case.
On the other side, if you want to iterate within your function, probably you can't get away with either passing a container (template) or passing two iterators (template) or doing fancy casts based on assumptions (risky).

Note that the member function `data` of a vector returns a pointer to the underlying array. If combined with `size`, you would have all what you need to iterate over the elements.
Anyway, in your case, `Base **` and `Derived **` are different beasts and you can't simply pass a `Derived **` to a function that accepts a `Base **`.

Any attempt to use functions from the standard library (as an example `std::for_each`) will probably end in using a template function somehow.

That's because `std::vector<Base *>` and `std::vector<Derived *>` **are** different types.

Comment: for_each is a template ;) And my DoSomething did much more then simply calling a single function. So I can't replace the given loop inside DoSomething by calling DoSomething from the outside. That is the bad side of simplified examples. Sorry ;)

Comment: @Klaus I don't see any other way to avoid a function template then. I'm sorry.

Comment: So it becomes more or less the question that it can be checked that the cast will be valid or not. Because it is typically valid ( as container for pointers derive from void* containers ), the case in my prog will do the job without any cost for code size and run time usage. Any template hack to get the answer of the validity of the cast here?

Comment: @Klaus Can you store tagged union in your vectors? This would solve, but it has a cost.

Comment: @Klaus Anyway, if you get the loop out of `DoSomerhing`, there are a lot of alternatives. If you want to loop inside the function, you haven't all those alternatives. Why can't you simply create to `std::vector<Base*>`? Maybe we can work around the issue in some other ways...

Comment: For me it is also a good answer that there is no "other" answer. Sometimes I did not find a solution but there is one. Asking here brings it up. If there is no other one, it is quite ok. It helps to see that I have nothing missed.